# How can I call a php function inside a tpl file?

Tags: php, function, task-parallel-library, smarty

I'm trying to call a php function inside a tpl file:

here is my function:

```
public function encrypt($tag){
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $tag, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
```

How can I call it from a tpl?

Please help me!

Comment: since you have a `public` visibility, this method is part of a class?

Comment: Yes this method is part of a class

Answer (score 0):

Seems like creating a custom modifier for smarty is good choice.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl

Or you may surround function call by {php}{/php} tags. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

```
{php}encrypt($tag){/php}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

smarty/libs/plugins/modifier.tag.php:

```
<?php 
function smarty_modifier_tag($tag)
{
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $tag, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
?>
```

smarty file:

```
{$foo|tag}
```

Comment: I'm creating a plugin for prestashop in PHP and smarty is autoloaded! so i can't access to smarty/libs/plugins/modifier.tag.php

Comment: Sorry i`m not familiar with prestashop. Try to create modifier.tag.php in tools\smarty\plugins\ folder

Answer (score 0):

Please make it clear what framework you are working in! if - though - you are working in drupal framework you can do php code for any tpl file in it's respective preprocess function in template.php file.

Comment: I'm creating a plugin for prestashop in PHP and smarty is autoloaded!